# Inflated Music Size on iPhone when Syncing

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

Frequently when I sync my iPhone to my iMac, the size bar will report that the amount of music on my phone is nearly double what it actually is (confirmed with a manual check). The phone will usually report that it is over capacity, but I can still copy applications and more music to it (as I should be able to). This doesn't happen on every sync, and sometimes when the sync is completed, it will shrink back down to the correct size. It's a major annoyance and makes it hard for me to see how much space I actually have used/free on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that it is related to iTunes Match. If you turn off iTunes Match on the iPhone, the iPhone will no longer register as over capacity.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This problem was occurring before iTunes Match was released though. And I do currently have iTunes Match switched off.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem.

1. Turn off iTunes Match, and make sure "manually manage music" is checked as an option when connecting the iPhone to your computer.
2. Remove all music from phone manually via iTunes.
3. Enable iTunes Match again and you should be all set with a cleared device and no more confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This problem was occurring before iTunes Match was released though. And I do currently have iTunes Match switched off.